# What is the Big O of rejection sampling from large sets of weighted items (like billions of records)?

Tags: weighted-sampling, notation, rejection-sampling

On average, how many "rejections" will I get before I get an acceptance (for large sets using weights)?

[This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/54562) suggested O(log n)?

Comment: It seems like what I'm looking for is connected to what's called the "acceptance probability".

Comment: [Here](http://playingwithr.blogspot.com/2011/06/rejection-sampling.html) you'll see when sampling with a Beta distribution with parameters 6 and 3 you get a little over double the amount of rejects than accepts after doing 100,000 samples. If someone can extrapolate this for a general case, I'd love that. I have  little experience with statsistics and probability.